# Change Greasepencil Color?

Tags: grease-pencil

is there an way to change those lines from grey to Black or do I need to draw it again?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Enter sculpt mode and use the strenght brush.

Comment: okay, I don't know if I got to this solution because I searched at the settings or somewhere else but there was no solution, so Thanks a lot, you saved me much time!